# How to python-telegram-bot concurrently to another asyncio logic?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

My bot must answer to user's commands and also send notifications about new content published on the site. I have to run this this two methods without blocking each other. How should i do this?

```
class Client():
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            token = os.environ['TOKEN']
        except KeyError:
            raise MissingEnvironmentVariable(
                'Ow, nooo "TOKEN" does not exist :sad owo:')
        self.application = Application.builder().token(token).build()
        self.cheker = HabrUpdatesCheker()
        self.subscriptions = SubscribtionsManager()
    

    async def notify_about_new_tasks(self):
        for tasks in await self.cheker.get_new_taks():
            for subscription in self.subscriptions.subscriptions:
                await self.application.bot.send_message(
                    chat_id=subscription['chat_id'],
                    text='')
        await asyncio.sleep(100)
        

    def run(self):
        self.application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
        self.application.run_polling()
        asyncio.run(self.notify_about_new_tasks())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_dotenv()
    client = Client()
    client.run()
```

I have tried to run notify and run polling in *run* method creating threads with asyncio, threading and multiprocessing. But all my code was blocking runtime.

Comment: see https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Concurrency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [docs of `run_polling`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.application.html#telegram.ext.Application.run_polling),

> it blocks the event loop until it receives a stop signal

and is hence not suitable for your setup. PTB provides two different approaches to your use case.

Firstly, you can use the built-in [`JobQueue`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions---JobQueue) for running repeated tasks instead of  does that manually in a loop.

Secondly, instead of using `run_polling` you can manually initialize, run & stop the application as explained in the docs of that method and also with more commentary in [the wiki](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Frequently-requested-design-patterns#running-ptb-alongside-other-asyncio-frameworks).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: I would be nice to have an example in the git repo

Comment: There is an [example](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.5/examples.html#examples-customwebhookbot) linked in the wiki page that I pointed to :)